# Not getting Paypal ExpressCheckOut

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, iphone-5

In my project I did PayWith PayPal method.
In that I used Pay With PayPal Button. Clicking on the button it will direct me on Paypal login.

After login the Pay Now button came and clicking on that payment will get success.
It is working correctly.

My question is,
I want to add CheckExpress Button first instead of pay with Paypal button
and want to get Continue button after clicking on that button instead of pay now button.

What to do ?

I used Pizza demo.

Any link related to any library or anything related to that checkExpress button will great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable "useraction=commit" to resolve this.  This variable changes button on the PayPal page from "Continue" to "Pay Now".  You still need to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment after the buyer returns to your site.

The purpose of "useraction=commit" is to allow you to finalize the transaction automatically, immediately when the buyer returns, instead of offering them one more confirmation screen.  You would do this in a scenario where you don't need to do things such as calculating shipping charges based on the address returned from GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and you are sure the original payment amount is the final amount.

So depending on what effect you are wanting, you would either pass over the variable "useraction" and set it to "commit", or not pass over the variable at all.

Comment: I have E-Commerce site and when user click on Continue button he will redirect to my site and then after he will pay. so i used the useraction=ECUSERACTION_CONTINUE but still the payment made in paypal not in my site.

Comment: The payment would be getting made from your site.  Its only the appearance of the text on the button on the PayPal page.  The buyer is still redirected back to your site, where your site has to execute a DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call to actually complete the transaction and charge the buyer.  I am not sure what the value of "ECUSERACTION_CONTINUE".  I couldn't find any reference to this value in developer docs, specs, or within PayPal's code.